# How can I identify missing features in a SharePoint site that has been restored from a different farm?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I recently inherited an application from a developer who is no longer with the company. This application restores SharePoint sites from backups and extracts metadata and files from lists in the site. The application runs on a SharePoint server and uses the Microsoft.SharePoint assemblies in C# and VB.Net.

The backups come to us from various outside companies, and some of them have custom features installed. SharePoint Health Analyzer shows a warning about "Missing server side dependencies". When I look at the report there is a lot of "[MissingFeature] Database [db name] has reference(s) to a missing feature..." etc. The previous developer was supposed to implement a check for missing features, but it is obviously not working.

How can I identify features that the restored site references, but are not installed on the farm?

Thanks!

RH

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Management Studion and check Features and FeatureTracking tables to see list of features, its' IDs, titles etc.

But do not modify these tables.

To solve missing features error. You can:
1. install missing feature (if you have it).
2. try to remove it (probably will fail as you don't have it).
3. as the last chance option you can create empty feature with the same ID as missing feature, pack it in WSP package and install it.

Comment: Thanks Mazin! How can I query those table to identify only the features that are not installed?

Comment: FeatureTracking table is the list of all features available for site colections and wwebs in the content database. Features table contains list of those activated on any web or site collection (have webID = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'). You must take ID from error message and try to find it in featuretracking table. This  will give you solutionid and disk folder where the feature content should be installed. You should get proper solution from original server and install it.

Comment: this application is designed to run unattended, so looking at the Health analyzer for missing features is not going to work for this scenario. Is there a sql query i can construct to get the same list of missing features as the health analyzer report?

Comment: But you write about Analyzer errors. You can try following script   select * FROM [WSS_Content].[dbo].[FeatureTracking]
  where FeatureId not in ( SELECT [Id]  FROM [SharePoint_Config].[dbo].[Objects]) It can identify potentially missing features. You can also check manually feature folders on restore server (in feature folder within 14 hive)